# Change indentation space of the tab in a QTextEdit in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5

I wonder if in PyQt5 you can change the size of the space that is made when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in a `QTextEdit`, because I do not know how to change it and it is very large.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this value using `setTabStopDistance` (in recent PyQt5 versions) or `setTabStopWidth` methods:

```
textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
textEdit.setTabStopDistance(size_of_tab_here)
textEdit.setTabStopWidth(size_of_tab_here)
```

Example of size set to 4 spaces:

```
textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
font = textEdit.font()
fontMetrics = QtGui.QFontMetricsF(font)
spaceWidth = fontMetrics.width(' ')
textEdit.setTabStopDistance(spaceWidth * 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want it?You can change the blank as you like.

I insert 4 space because I think it is standard with python.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import sys
class TextEdit(QtWidgets.QTextEdit):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(TextEdit,self).__init__(parent=None)
    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Tab:                
            tc = self.textCursor()
            tc.insertText("    ")
            return
        return QtWidgets.QTextEdit.keyPressEvent(self,event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = TextEdit()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```